# Google drive high data usage

Tags: mobile-data, google-drive, background-data

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post...

Yesterday, i opened Google drive to check and spreadsheet and everything looked fine. Today i see that this night Google drive has used about 600MB of mobile data on the background. It's been 2 weeks since i connected to a WiFi network and around 1 month since i opened Drive. Obviously, i have now disabled background data usage for that app on Android settings but I'm afraid that this can happen again with another app.

- What has been using that much mobile data (maybe sync or updates?) and how can i avoid this happening in the future?
- Is it safe to disable background data usage on every app (except messaging apps)?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Did you download something using a browser? In some MI devices, for some reason, 
some downloads initiated by browser unnecessarily are directed into Google drive app even when defaults are off.

Comment: I have a mi A2, but i haven't downloaded anything except that spreadsheet, that i opened trough a link to drive.google.com